# Can a Loxodromic Transformation be the Composition of 2 Reflections?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been reading "Visual complex Analysis," and it proved that a Mobius transformation whose multiplier is real can be written as the composition of two reflections in circles/lines (i.e., inversions), and so can a Mobius transformation whose multiplier has absolute value $1$. Of course, this means that a loxodromic transformation, whose multiplier is neither real nor of unit norm, can be writtwen as the product of four reflections. The book then claimed that this was the least number of reflections, but didn't seem to prove it. Can a particular loxodromic transformation be written as the product of two reflections? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't enough of them.

The Möbius group is $6$-dimensional (as a real manifold), since it can be identified with $\Bbb{C}P^3$.

There are at most $5$ dimensions worth of transformations that can be written as the composition of two reflections. You pick a center and a radius for each reflection, which is again $6$ real dimensions of arbitrary choice, but any given transformation comes from at least a $1$-parameter family of such choices (the two radii are both scaling factors, so you can rejigger one to compensate for changes in the other).

Comment: And it's the case that the nonloxodromic ones have dimension $5$?

Comment: It is: both "the multiplier is real" and "the multiplier has modulus $1$" are $1$-dimensional constraints. That said, this only answers your question if your question was "do there exist loxodromic transformations which cannot be so written"; if you wanted to know if every loxodromic transformation requires $4$ reflections, I think that requires an actual computation...

Comment: The book proved that $4$ reflections are sufficient, but not that they were necessary.

So if each has a $1$ dimensional constraint, that means that each is $6-1=5$ dimensions? But doesn't that give $10$ dimensions in total, too many?

Comment: That just means there are lots of different ways to decompose each Möbius transform into reflections. (You can map high-dimensional spaces onto lower-dimensional spaces; you just can't go the other way around as long as everything is smooth -- which, in this case, it is.)

Comment: Oh okay, but how do I show that the nonloxodromic ones have dimension $5$?